# Best strategy to handle incoming midi signal from MIDIReadProc in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, coremidi, nsslider

I have to move some `NSSlider` by hardware midi controller, I have programmed a midi learn procedure to assign hardware cursor to `NSSlider`(sub class of), and up there it's all right. Inside `MIDIReadProc`, I handle moving `NSSlider` wich depends from incoming control and value, but now when I move hardware cursor, Sliders can be move one for time, it is like moving cursor stop the others.

My question is, what is best strategy to handle cursor moving concurrently ?
1 . Should I have to handle with a separated thread ?
2 . Should I have one `FIFO` data structure of `MIDIPacket` and processing that out of `MIDIReadProc`(with some concurrency separated process) ?

I'm sorry for my english.
Thanks for attention.

a.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do any UI synchronisation inside `MIDIReadProc` callback.

This callback is called from a high priority realtime thread so you must avoid doing anything that could be "too long" in it.

As you said you can use a FIFO and treat that in another thread (for instance the main thread).

Comment: I'm realy happy for your answer, for now I call one method inside 'MIDIReadProc' callback, and inside the method wich has the packetlist reference, I create a new thread wich dispatch the packetlist to UI based on cc assigned, but I have always the same problem, it's better than previous code but it isn't what I want. Using a FIFO is a good choose but where can I dispacth the FIFO? In another thread in background wich continually escapes the FIFO? Thanks for attention.

Comment: @tritono: Creating a thread inside the callback is typically what I call "anything that could be "too long"". Having a background is a good idea indeed.

Comment: Thank you, i will adopt your suggestions. I will tell you the results about.

Comment: At this moment in `MIDIReadProc` insert `MIDIPacket` inside a FIFO crates with `NSMutableArray`. When I initialize the class wich handle midi, I create a new thread(init it) and set his priority and start it. I need a NSRunLoop which dispatch a FIFO while `[FIFO count]>0`. But something is wrong because I don't know how to set-up and handle the RunLoop. I need a good guide to work with `NSRunLoop`. Here pseudo-code:

Comment: @tritono: I am not familiar with Objective-C, I am more a c++ guy. Maybe you should ask look at [ObjC](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/objc-language) or [Cocoa-dev](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/cocoa-dev) mailing list.

Comment: thanks, yesterday I have tryed a solution for a thread with timer which executes a procedure to dispatch `FIFO` every x ms. It seems work now I need to test performance. I hope to answer my question as soon as.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, to update 'NSSlider', moving sliders updating code in kvo path and using a background process separated thread to update a slider ui and value.
After, I have separated ui control with assignment from that without and using a 'NSMutableDictionary' with key value equal at midi control to identify the 'NSSlider' faster in MIDIReadProc.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: get attention... at this link you can find a good document wich explain midi lag. [link](https://www.haiku-os.org/documents/dev/introduction_to_midi_part_2)